# Smooth transition of values in a multithread enviroment

Tags: c++, multithreading, concurrency, thread-priority

How do you  transition a value from **x** to **y** smoothly and at a speed determined by another thread.

Let me try to explain with my concrete problem, as it illustrates it quite well.

I am working on an audio playing application. When you abruptly pause the flow of samples to the sound API, thus creating a **big value difference** between consequent samples (i.e. changing a sine wave to zeroes), you get a **popping sound**.

To avoid this, you need to **smoothly transition the volume** from the current value to zero.

**PortAudio**, the library im using, processes audio on a **background thread** which uses a **callback** function when it needs data or has data for me. The buffer with the sound samples and volume value are both arguments to this callback, so i have **no control over how frequently they are read.**

How do you achieve the volume transition with these circumstances:

- No thread priority control on audio thread (presumably one of the highest), so **no control over read frequency.**
- Can't really block callback, as it would cause audio errors.
- Data protection is not necessary - won't create noticeable errors.

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

I feel I didn't go into enough detail for fear of over-specifying the problem. I'd like to concreticize it some more.

Basically, the stream of data can be described with:

`Loader (async producer) -> Buffer -> Player (async consumer)`

What adds to the difficulty is that the buffer operates like a **queue** (for future implementation of a lock-free queue and data integrity), so i cannot touch the audio data to modify a part of it to be trasitionary.

This may be a design flaw , oversight or just tunnel-vision on my part, so this may be subject to change.

Furthermore, i wanted to leave the buffer to just handle the raw data, as the Player object is responsible for the actual playing and i felt like volume control was its responsibility.

A simplified callback can be described with this example code:

```
static int bufferCallback(const void *inputBuffer, void *outputBuffer,
              unsigned long framesPerBuffer,
              const PaStreamCallbackTimeInfo *timeInfo,
              PaStreamCallbackFlags statusFlags,
              void *userData)
{
    /* Cast data passed through stream to our structure. */
    simple_player<float> *data = (simple_player<float> *)userData;
    float *out = (float *)outputBuffer;
    unsigned int i;
    (void)inputBuffer; /* Prevent unused variable warning. */

    float into;
    i = 0;
    unsigned int more;
    while (i < framesPerBuffer)
    {
        more = data->buffer->get(into);
        if (!more)
        {
            return paContinue;
        }
        *out = clip::soft_clip(into*data->volume);
        out++;
        more = data->buffer->get(into);

        if (!more)
        {
            return paContinue;
        }
        *out = clip::soft_clip(into*data->volume);
        out++;
        i++;
    }
    return paContinue;
}
```

**Note:** Upon further consideration, i don't think i can sync a thread to the PortAudio processing thread. Instead i would let the callback itself transition volume by extending the player and doing calculations in the callback, like:

```
static int bufferCallback(const void *inputBuffer, void *outputBuffer,
              unsigned long framesPerBuffer,
              const PaStreamCallbackTimeInfo *timeInfo,
              PaStreamCallbackFlags statusFlags,
              void *userData)
{
    /*Callback body*/
    if(data->volume!=data->target_volume)
    {
        data->volume+=data->volume_delta;
    }
    return paContinue;
}
```

Comment: Is'nt it possible to control the size of the buffer you provide?

Comment: The buffer size is not relevant. The volume im referring to is the volume of the audio.

Comment: The buffer contains the audio data, right? Depending on bitrate it should be possible to calculate the length of the actual audio played from the buffer, which should be a possibility to control how frequently your callback function is called. Do i misunderstand something?

Comment: Ah, I see. Sadly, PortAudio only consumes as much of the buffer as it feels like, and when it feels like. The callback is called when it is ready to process data, depending on underlying host api , OS and hardware, and then only consumes an amount determined by the above factors, and only  within the callback do I get the amount it wants to consume.

Comment: You're supplying the audio data. Instead of setting it to zeroes abruptly, you need to supply samples of steadily-decreasing amplitude (until they reach zero). These values can be generated by multiplying the normal sample value by a factor that starts at 1.0 and smoothly goes to 0.0 *as a function of time* (you should be able to calculate the time elapsed since the 'stop' was requested one way or another). One such common function is 'smoothstep'; another is 'smootherstep' -- you supply the fraction of time out of the total fade-out interval that has passed, and it returns a multiplier.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I've revised my question and I feel like my code has some deeper flaws than this. I'll reconsider this method.